# How to login in react js using firebase database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, forms, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have created a table (usertbl) for users in firebase as you can see in below screenshot. I want to use the data of this table for login purpose. As you can see fields 'Username' & 'Password' showing on the right side.

**I am trying to achieve:**

1. if user is exist and password is matching then login and show 'user name'.
2. if user is not exist or password is not matching then show 'user name or password is wrong'.

**here is user table**
[image]

**And here is the login form that i will use in react js.**

[image]

```
    <form>
  <div className='row'>
    <div className='col-12 mb-3'>
      <h3>Admin Login</h3>
    </div>
    <div className='col-lg-5'>
      <div className="form-group mb-3">
        <div>Username</div>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" autoComplete="on" />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group mb-3">
        <div>Password</div>
        <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" autoComplete="off" />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group mb-3">
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

thanks

Comment: This does not seem to be a specific problem. Why don't you explore creating a simple login functionality with ReactJS and Firebase?